# Решето Эратосфена. Реализация из Седжвика

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм

```
class Primes{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int N = Integer/parseInt(args[0]);
        boolean[] a = new boolean[N];
        for (int i = 2; i<N; i++) a[i] = true;
        for (int i = 2; i<N; i++)
            if (a[i] != false)
                for (int j = i; j*i < N; j++)
                    a[i*j] = false;
        for (int i = 2; i < N; i++)
            if (i > N - 100) // Зачем это проверять?
                if (a[i]) Out.print(" " + i);
        Out.println();
    }
}
```

Не понимаю, зачем в последнем цикле с выводом чисел делать ограничение `if (i > N - 100)` ?

P.S описание программы, которое приведено в учебнике:
Данная программа предназначена для печати всех простых чисел, меньших целого числа, заданного аргументом в командной строке. Для этого вычисляется массив логических значений, в котором `a[i]` равно `true`, если `i` простое число, и `false` в противном случае. Сначала во все элементы массива заносится `true` для обозначения, что еще нет известных составных чисел. Затем в элементы массива, индексы которых оказываются составными числами, заносится `false`. Если после установки в `false` всех делителей простых чисел, меньших `i`, элемент `a[i]` все еще равен `true`, то его индекс является простым числом

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Что будет, если при запуске программы введут очень большое N - миллион, десять? Памяти под массив-то хватит, и программа сработает довольно быстро. А вот ждать полдня вывода на экран сотен тысяч строк - ни к чему. Поэтому выводятся простые числа только из последней сотни - для визуального контроля. При малых N, когда всю таблицу простых чисел можно увидеть на одном экране, это не мешает.

Comment: А разве вывод на экран более тяжеловесная процедура, чем собственно сам расчет? Почему программа сработает быстро, а на выводе будет тормозить?

Comment: @Dmitry да, ввод/вывод как правило гораздо медленнее вычислений. Вот ориентировочные числа для задержки, связанной с вводом/выводом https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~rcs/research/interactive_latency.html